EXCEL: formula to extract data from a table
EXCEL:
I have a table in the cell range A2 to G4.
I want to find a value that can be in any cell in the range A2 to F4 and display the corresponding value in column G.
I've tried creating forums with various functions but none of them work...
Anyone who can help?


A very basic solution could be:
=TOCOL(IFS(A2:G4=B8,G2:G4),3)

Do you have more than a single value to look for in B9 or was that just for demonstration purposes?
